# ChainlinkClient.sol v0.8.0 NOT working (request.add("get", "<url>"))

Tags: solidity, truffle, oracles, chainlink, solidity-0.8.x

Im am relatively new to using ChainLinks ORACLE contract in solidity. I have recently managed to successfully integrate their VRFConsumerBase.sol in my consumer contract to generate random numbers. However, when i want to integrate and use their Client to make simple Get request to my API, it throws this error upon compiling

`CompileError: TypeError: Member "add" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct Chainlink.Request memory`

I am currently using **Truffle v5.1.65 & Sol 0.8.0**. I am importing my ChainLink files as shown below :

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/dev/ChainlinkClient.sol";
```

Here's My function :

```
    function uploadTokenDataToServer(NFT memory nft) public{

     require(LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= linkFee, "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet");


    Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.confirmUpload.selector);
    
    string memory finalURL = append(nft.ID,nft.creator,nft.desc) ;
    
    request.add("get", finalURL);
  
    return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, linkFee);
}
```

It seems that the `add` function is not being detected when compiling. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solidity v0.8 contracts for Chainlink are still in active development, use the [v0.6 contracts](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/tree/develop/evm-contracts/src/v0.6) until they are ready.

`import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";`

For future reference, the contracts are currently in the dev folder of the v0.8 directory, indicating they aren't ready for production.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that! I could not find a direct answer

Comment: **UPDATE:** As of Aug 07, 2021, The issue is still present even though the `ChainlinkClient.sol` isn't in the `v0.8/dev/` directory.